# Is it possible to add an attachment file to Visualforce without a controller class?

Tags: apex, visualforce

Is there a way you can add an attachment to a visualforce email template without using an controller class?

Comment: What attachment would it be? Will there be any condition or you wanna attach some static attachment to your template?

Comment: You can probably do it using Remote Objects or some other Javascript approach.

Comment: For example adding attachments to quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> without using an controller class

So it mean refer to Apex Class, then [jsforce](https://jsforce.github.io/)

Below just a code snip, and you'll need to initialise connection see https://jsforce.github.io/start/#setup

```
jsForceConn.sobject('Attachment').create({ 
            ParentId: 'mysalesforceContactID',
            Name : fileName,
            Body: base64data,
            ContentType : fileType,  
        }, 
        function(err, uploadedAttachment) {
            console.log(err,uploadedAttachment);
    });
```

Comment: Oops! ahh... email template, not just VF page :-D

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

[Uploading Attachments to Salesforce using Javascript Remoting](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjVicTXmKbSAhXDM48KHeHHCLwQFggZMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fforceadventure.wordpress.com%2F2013%2F07%2F19%2Fuploading-attachments-to-salesforce-using-javascript-remoting%2F&usg=AFQjCNE9svYf-Me0iCef7cnBuCtDPoQgMQ&sig2=iRVWgqRRF7JusDZ--XfPdQ&bvm=bv.147448319,d.c2I)